# searching vectors in c++

Tags: c++, search, vector, find

```
I have 3 string vectors
1) contains words 
2) contains definitions 
3) contains types
```

how do i use the `find()` function to look for words in the `words vector`  and also get the `number(row)` for which that word is in. as i need the number to get the data from the other 2 vectors. also how do i look for similar words for example words that has "logy", or for words between a user specified range "like longer than 4 characters"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

class Files {
private:
  
    vector<string>words;
    vector<string>definitions;
    vector<string>types;
public:
    void read();
    //void intro();
    void displayall(vector <string>& words, vector <string>& types, vector <string>& definitions);
    void find(vector <string>& words, vector <string>& types, vector <string>& definitions);
};

void Files::find(vector <string>& words, vector <string>& types, vector <string>& definitions)
{
    string search;
    cout << "Enter word : " << endl;
    cin >> search;
    //here i need a funtion to find the user enter word form the vector
}


void Files::displayall(vector <string> & words, vector <string>&  types, vector <string>&  definitions) 
{
   
    
    cout << "This function displays the whole dictionary " << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
            cout <<'\n'<< words.at(i) << '\n' << types.at(i) << '\n' << definitions.at(i) << endl;
    
    
}
void Files::read()
{
    string word;
    string definition;
    string type;
    string blank;
    int i = 0;
    ifstream out("Text.txt");
   
    do
    {
        (getline(out, word, '\n'));
        words.push_back(word); 
        getline(out, definition, '\n');
        definitions.push_back(definition);
        getline(out, type, '\n');
        types.push_back(type);
        getline(out, blank, '\n');

        i++;
        cout << "number of line " << i << ' ' << word << endl;
    } while (!out.eof());
   
    displayall(words,definitions,types);

}


int main()
{
    Files d;
    d.read();
    
}
```

Comment: [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to find the element, then [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) to get the "distance" to the returned iterator (which also happens to be the vector index).

Comment: Take a step back and define a type that represents one of your entries, like `struct Entry { string word; string definition; string type;};`. Then you can use a single vector and save many headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Like this.

```
auto i = find(words.begin(), words.end(), search);
if (i != words.end())
{
    auto pos = i - words.begin();
    // do something
}
else
{
    // word not found
}
```

Do you not have anywhere where you can look this stuff up? This is about as basic a use of `std::find` as it gets, so you should be able to answer these kind of questions yourself.

I suppose your other questions could be solved using `std::find_if`, or just by writing a loop that implements the search condition you require.

Comment: hi john i tried the above code that you had given but t gives me errors like so https://ibb.co/hsTjvRd. Please help

Comment: @AkashDeSilvaTry `std::find` instead of `find`. I should have noticed that you have a method called `Files::find` which is confusing the compiler. Don't forget to `#include <algorithm>` as well.

Comment: @AkashDeSilva I realise now that I may have misunderstood your question. When you said 'how to I use the find() function' where you refering to your own find function? I assumed you were referring to `std::find`. Anyway my answer does work, but it's not what I would recommend if you weren't specifically asking about `std::find`. I would just recommend that you write a simple loop.